# How to use a M-.file in a parfor loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

my code inside a **parfor loop** is getting longer and longer and I would like to split it up. Having parts of the code saved **in different script files** seems logical and very attractive and since it doesn't change anything except where the code is saved it seems like it should work. But it doesn't.

I get the usual "**Transparency violation error**".

The problem seems typical but I did not find this question asked or answered anywhere.

Below is a small **working example**.

*(Yes, this could be made as a function. But in case of many more Input and Output variables this becomes really ugly imo and probably also slower due to communicating the arguments)*

```
C = NaN(10,1); %Result vector
parfor loop = 1:10
    a = 1;
    b = 2;

    MFile_Test %Run the m-file which contains only one line:
    % c = a + b;

    C(loop)=c;

end
```

the MFile_Test is a script just containing the line one line c = a + b.

I am beginning to understand why parallel computing has an issue here but not how to solve it. Since this would be possible without any problem if I just had the line c = a + b inside the parfor file I cannot belief there is no simple way to solve this (e.g. in the worst case something like tell matlab to load the text from another file and run it as code here and now).

If there are alternative ways to structure my code without using the script files (and, if possible, without using only functions ;)) I would appreciate such comments as well, of course.

Many thanks,
Daniel

Comment: btw, I also experimented with
addAttachedFiles(gcp,{'mydata'}) 

or using save('mydata') and then load('mydata') inside the script

but neither worked.

Comment: I don't know any other way than functions. `parfor` would need to have reference to every variable being used. If you call a script, that reference is lost. In short, your script is no more transparent. See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/108536-error-transparency-violation-error) and [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/02/using-parfor-loops-getting-up-and-running/). If your issue is that code becomes ugly due to the number of input and output variables, then you can use `structures` or `cells`.

Comment: As a hacky alternative to passing all the variables to a function, you can save the workspace in the calling script and load it again inside the function.

Comment: Why are you avoiding functions?  MATLAB scripts are fantastic for prototyping, especially cell mode scripts, but should not be used for structured programming.  I strongly recommend functions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 
I just started using cells for that matter, Parag, but feel like it makes my code less clear. But ok, I will continue using it.
The option of saving and reloading the workspace sounds neat to me, I will look into it, thanks Cecilia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parfor` has various constraints that make using scripts inside the loop generally a bad option. The main constraint is that the text of the `parfor` loop must be analysable to see what new variables might be created - this is referred to as ["transparency" in the doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/variables-and-transparency-in-parfor-loops.html#bq__7bq-1). Try using a function instead.

Comment: Ok then I will have to. Still don't understand why the text of the script can't simply be read in from matlab equal to the text in the main file, but I guess thats me.
So I will mark the answer as correct to close the question.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

So, for other people or for possible hints to improve, here is how I did it with a function and loading the input variables.

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
save('Input.mat');

pseudo_input = NaN;%for the function

D= NaN(10,1);%result vector
parfor loop = 1:10
D(loop) = Parfor_Fun_Test(pseudo_input);
end
```

And the function looks like this:

```
function d = Parfor_Fun_Test(InputArgs)
load('Input.mat');
d = a + b ;
end
```

I would have preferred to also save the output, i.e. 'd', within the function and then load it in the parfor loop, but that causes an error, probably because the same file is accessed for loading and saving at the same time by different parallel workers. So this will have to do it. (This can apparently be circumvented by [saving under a different name](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/135285-how-do-i-use-save-with-a-parfor-loop-using-parallel-computing-toolbox) each time, but that would probably really slow down the code.)

By the way, it seems that using cells or structures is slightly faster, but then I have to write the code inside the function as this, I assume:

```
d = Input.a + Input.b ;
```

which is more ugly and more work. So I use the save and load method as above for now.